# Recursive functions duplicate work

Tags: algorithm

some recursive calls have duplicate work. For example in the following case, the running

```
T(n) = (sum from i to zero to (n-1) T(i) ) + n
```

with `T(0)=1` .there is one (direct) recursive call of each size from 0 to n -1,
plus O(n) additional work.

Solving for T(n), we find that it grows exponentially.

What kind of tree above recursive call generates, is this same as Divide and conquer tree?

Thanks!

Comment: that's a recurrence relation, it doesn't generate any calls...

Comment: I am not sure on what you are asking. The function above is an recurrence relation, which is a type of mathematical functions. There is no such thing as a "recursive call" in mathematics. You get recursive calls, when you try to implement that function in the naive way (there might be better ways). Also you are mentioning the duplicate work. Yes in the naive implementation there is duplicate work, which can easily be eliminated by not using recursion to calculate this function (e.g. dynamic programming).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to provide *some* answer to this... the wording is poor, but perhaps you can take this and use my understanding to refine your meaning.

Let's assume you're asking about a function to compute T(n), implemented recursively as

```
  T(n)
  1. r := 0
  2. for i := 0 to n-1 do
  3.    r := r + T(i)
  4. r := r + n
  5. return r
```

A tree for this recursion would look like this...

```
      _______________________T(n)_____________________
     /       /          /            \                \
  T(0)    T(1)       T(2)            T(3)      ...    T(n-1)
           |         / \          /   |   \              |
          T(0)    T(0) T(1)     T(0) T(1) T(2) ...      ...
                       ...           ...  ....
```

The tree is quite similar to the recursion tree you get for evaluation of the Fibonacci sequence; in fact, you get the same tree if you limit the summation to be between [n-2, n-1] instead of [0, n-1]. To find the running time of this, since the non-recursive part of the function is O(1), we just need to count how many recursive calls are made.

T(n) will make n recursive calls, T(0), T(1), ..., T(n-1). As a result of calling T(n), T(n-1) will be called only once; T(n-2) will be called twice (once as a result of T(n), again as a result of T(n-1)). T(n-3) will be called once as a result of T(n), once as a result of T(n-1), and twice as a result of the two calls to T(n-2), for a total of 4 calls. As we can now see, T(n-k) is called 2^(k-1) times as a result of T(n);l so if we sum the number of calls for each k between 1 and n, we get 2^n - 1... right? So we get a time complexity for this function of O(2^n)... just like naive Fibonacci.

To get the growth rate of the value returned by the function, we can look at the function itself as the recurrence relation of some other piece of code. In that case, we can start listing a few terms...

```
  T(0) = c
  T(1) = c + 1
  T(2) = c + (c +1) + 2 = 2c + 1+2
  T(3) = c + (c + 1) + (2c + 1+2) + 3 = (4c +1+1+2+3)
  T(4) = c + (c + 1) + (2c + 1+2) + (4c + 1+1+2+3) + 4 = 8c +1+1+1+1+2+2+3+4
  ...
  T(n) = c*2^(n-1) + 1*2^(n-2) + 2*2^(n-3) + 3*2^(n-4) + ... + (n-1)*2^0 + n
       = c*2^(n-1) + sum(i*2^(n-i-1) for i := 1 to n-1) + n
```

We can simplify this summation a bit...

```
  T(n) = c*2^(n-1) * 2^(n-1)*sum(i*2^(-i) for i := 1 to n-1) + n
```

So the problem of getting a closed-form solution for the growth order of the function is reduced to finding the growth order of the summation i*2^(-i). My money says that you can do better than growth order... is there a closed form for this? Anyway, this should be enough to help, if not a complete answer to your question.